# Using state design pattern for cocos2d game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The game I am creating is a word puzzle game. You start out with a menu, where the user decides wether to go single player or multiplayer for instance. 
If they choose Single Player then they have the option to play 3 different modes.

- Practice

*There is no timer*

- Stress

*The player have to do a puzzle within 10 seconds repeatedly, until it deosn't manage to do the puzzle within the 10 seconds and they "die"*

- Time battle

*The player has 2 mins to do as many puzzles as possible.*

You see, the actual game play doesn't change but the only thing that changes is how the time is managed. 
I read your articles and I found that the State pattern would fit quite nice, and now the only problem I have is how I could implement that pattern.

Should I make sub states as in a menu state abstraction and a game play abstraction or should I just create one universal game state abstraction and then ignore calls like "*handleMenuSelection*"?

I can't find any good tutorials online covering this in cocos2d. I can find a lot of small demos but it is hard to transform that into a big application when I have never touched a design pattern before besides the OOP design.

Btw. your links was very helpful opening up my mind for new ideas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good to have one singleton class (shared object) that maintains all stats.

Example: Say MyGame is used to store all game stats.
//in MyGame.h

```
typedef enum
{
    kGameMode_Practice = 1001,
    kGameMode_Stress,
    kGameMode_TimeBattle,
 }GameMode;



@interface MyGame: NSObject
{
    GameMode  mGameMode;
    int       mHighScore;
} 
@property(nonatomic,assign) GameMode  gameMode;
```

@property(nonatomic,assign) int  highScore;

```
+(MyGame*)sharedGameObject;
```

//In MyGame.mm

```
static MyGame *gGame = nil;

  @implementation MyGame
  @synthesize gameMode=mGameMode;
  @synthesize highScore=mHighScore;

 +(MyGame*)sharedGameObject
 {
    if(!gGame)
    {
        gGame = [[MyGame alloc] init];
    }
    return gGame;
 }

 -(void)saveData //Call this from applicationWillResignActive
 {
         NSUserDefaults *userDafs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [userDafs setInteger:self.highScore forKey:@"highScore"];
         [userDafs setInteger:self.gameMode forKey:@"gameMode"];

         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 }

 -(void)loadData //call this from UIApplication didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
 { 
     NSUserDefaults *userDafs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     self.highScore = [userDafs integerForKey:@"highScore"]
     self.gameMode = (GameMode)[userDafs integerForKey:@"gameMode"]

 }
```

//You can set game mode on selecting menu button

```
 [MyGame sharedGameObject].gameMode = kGameMode_Practice
```

//To check anywhere in the game

```
   if([MyGame sharedGameObject].gameMode == kGameMode_Practice)
```

Also save these value at app termination and load same when app starts.

```
    [[MyGame sharedGameObject] saveData];
```

Based on game mode you can change game play. Use single general class for game play logic and check game mode and do tweak..when u design 3 separate class for 3types then change in one needs to be updated in all files in future..so good to have general code as much as possible.

Comment: This is what I would use personally - I believe a singleton which you can pull settings from is the simplest method of implementing what you want.

Comment: I think this is useful as well, but you end up with so much if's and switches, and the code will become like a headset in the pocket. I am also going to support multiplayer later in the game. Would I just put a bool in the game manager telling if it is multiplayer or not? The Multiplayer will be turn based, so the game play wouldn't depend on it besides that only some of the game modes will be allowed. (no need for endless practice mode, when multiplaying)

Comment: yes, like highScore you can use one more bool variable to maintain states about multiplayer or not..hope u got idea. Also you need to save and load these stats in NSUserDefaults at game start and end.

Comment: Hehe, no need to save other things than highscore :) but i get your point, but normally I use NSCoding for such things, because I always end up using complex data. Accepted answer and if nobody else comes with a better solution you will receive the bounty :) (Tried but it says 9 hours wait) edit: thanks to you I have already implemented the game modes. Quite easy actually and only like 200 lines of code in the game scene :)

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to suggest a good design guideline given that there is very little information. Trying to guess a bit, I would suggest you to read about the [Strategy Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) and the [State Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) ([another link](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state)), as it may be suitable for what you are doing, and it would be a clean way to manage multiple game modes.